# How to find and remove all banners related to a campaign page?

Tags: search, delete, pages

at the company I work for we manage a large SharePoint installation.
Recently our client asked us to delete all banners related to an old campaign. The banners are all pointing to the same page.

Is there a way to easily find all the banners so that they can be removed?

Comment: Nor banners, nor campaign pages are core concepts in a SharePoint environment, leading me to believe that there is some sort of customization or greater amount of configuration made in your environment to support this. That fact makes it difficult to give you a good answer on your question.

Comment: By banners I mean a simple image plus a link, the campaign page it's just a page all the these links point to.

Comment: Ok, try reading this post and see if it helps you http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-sharepoint-2010-incoming-links/